# Android profiler tool is avail for flutter app in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter, android-profiler

In **Android studio** we have handy tool to **Measure app performance** with Android Profiler, through that we can able to trace our apps Memory, network, CPU usages..

I don't see that option tool in my studio when i'm working with flutter app's, `Android Profiler` is available for flutter app too in android studio ?

if yes, how we have to enable it (or) any other way to trace flutter app's performance ?

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani Link's question & this is not same, both questions are totally different.

Comment: oh right, sry , i deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go: **Run->Profile** and click in triangle, **Profile**

[image]